# CodeIgniter returns a blank response, no error message. (Possibly related to filemtime(): stat failed)

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've written some code as part of an existing CodeIgniter 2 application, which is designed to extract some data from the database, generate preview images, transform the data, then send it to a third-party search service. It works perfectly on my development environment. However, after deploying it to the staging environment, I get an empty 200 response from the server.

The Apache error log shows nothing, the Apache access log just has a single entry with the 200 code. This is despite `error_reporting` being set to `E_ALL` and `display_errors` being set to `true`. The only error message I am seeing is in the `.php` log file generated by CodeIgniter within the application directory. Here it is:

```
ERROR - 2017-04-18 12:40:08 --> Severity: Warning  --> filemtime(): stat failed for /var/www/vhosts/gvip.io/staging/current/wwwroot/cache/made/23f4b9ae97bceb7ea30e71bdc2a48ece_27_27_ffffff_all_2_s_c1.JPG /var/www/vhosts/gvip.io/staging/releases/20170417130504/.app/libraries/Ce_image.php 2236
```

Sure enough, line 2236 of the Ce_image library does include a call to `filemtime`:

```
$finaltime = @filemtime( $this->path_final ); //filetime of cached image
```

However,

1. I don't see how this error would cause the application to die (and not return the expected HTML response). It is listed as Warning, not Fatal.
2. If this is the problem, I'm honestly rather lost as to how to debug it. The line that's pointed to in the error message is part of a library, nested inside a long function, called from another function, etc.

It's certainly true that the file referenced in the error message doesn't exist.

Interestingly, the first time I ran the code, about 92 similar error messages were generated, each with a different file name. On subsequent runs, it only generated one error message each time (with the same file name each time).

I tried setting the CodeIgniter logging level to `4` (all messages), but it didn't really reveal anything new. Apart from some messages about initializing helpers and classes, it just had around 3300 lines stating `XSS Filtering completed`. (The query only has around 2600 records, so I'm not sure why 3300.)

Comment: do you then not need the file that does not exist in order for the library to function properly?

Comment: @coderodour Not really sure! The method that line is contained within is called `is_cached`, and the DocBlock for it reads:
`Determines the filename that should be created for the manipulated image and whether or not it is cached.`
So without reading through the whole code, it seems plausible that the method would check to see whether the requested image file had already been generated previously by looking for a file that might not yet exist (before then going on to generate it if it does not yet exist).